# Delete images that are in elequent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I have two models that are in one to many relationship:

Tour.php

```
    public function photos()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Photo');
}
```

Photo.php

```
    public function tour()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Tour');
}
```

I want to delete these photos from folder when tour related to these photos is deleted. These photos are located id in (public/images/slides)

This is what i tried to do:

```
    public function destroy($id)
{        
    $tour = Tour::find($id);
    $tour->country()->detach();
    File::delete(public_path('/images/featured_image/'.$tour->featured_image));
    File::delete(public_path('/images/banner/'.$tour->banner));
    File::delete(public_path('/images/slides/'.$tour->photos->path));
    $tour->delete();

    Session::flash('success', 'The tour is sucessfully deleted.');
    return redirect()->route('tours.index');
}
```

And i got error of:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$path
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `$tour->photos` is a collection, and you can't access one property on a collection.

You need to run a loop

```
foreach($tour->photos() as $photo){
   File::delete(public_path($photo->path));
}
```

But I would go with different way

On You `Tour Model (Tour.php)` create a boot method

```
 protected static function boot() {
            parent::boot();
            static::deleting(function($tour) {
            $tour->photos()->delete();
        });
    }
```

And on your `Photo Model (Photo.php)` as well

```
protected static function boot() {
            parent::boot();
            static::deleting(function($photo) {
            if ( File::exists(public_path($photo->path))) {
                    File::delete(public_path($photo->path));
                } 
            }
        });
    }
```

Think of it as Chain, When you delete `Tour` this will trigger deleting for `Photos` when deleting `Photos` files are deleting as well.

This way it works Both way if you delete a `Tour` or you keep `Tour` and delete just `Photo`

Comment: None of these above did the job nor returned any error.

Comment: @ZacharyDale then your doing something wrong, copy somewhere your Code Model/Controller (Like pastebin or something) and also one example of `$photo->path`

Comment: I realised that `/images/slides/7212637200_ba233060a3_o.jpg` is saved in my db colum `path`. I changed my code to `foreach($tour->photos() as $photo)
        {
           File::delete(public_path($photo->path));
        } `  but this is also not deleting the image.

Comment: @check File Permissions is owned by web-server?

Comment: How do I check that ? I'm still developing in localhost. Well deleting other images `File::delete(public_path('/images/featured_image/'.$tour->featured_image));  File::delete(public_path('/images/banner/'.$tour->banner));` didn't require any permission.

Comment: Try `debug` when you run loop try `var_dump($photo)` check the output,
Also try changing `$tour->photos()` to `$tour->photos` (see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)